# Is there anywhere you can get a super key for the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

Like, a physical key to swap the Windows Start key with the Ubuntu Super key?
Is there anywhere I can buy such a thing, or have I gone to the wrong place and asked? :P

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not best or most beautiful solution but you could  cover it with a sticker. Stickers can be purchased from canonical [web shop](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?currency=USD&products_id=718) or second  solution is to request a free stickers from System76 [web page](https://www.system76.com/community/stickers/)

Comment: I know, my sticker has just worn out (twas quite old), so I wondered if there was a physical key. But thanks for the answer :D